# How to Programmatically Extract Text from a Flash Webpage

Tags: javascript, flash

I'm trying to write a data crawler to examine some swf files to search for some text. The certain text I am trying to extract is hidden until I press a button on the webpage and an overlay displays the text. How would I go so in extracting this text? I've decompiled the swf file and noticed that the text is dynamically updated rather than static. I'm not familiar with flash/actionscript but the text is stored in a function variable videoData.title. Is there any way I can access this variable through javascript or java?